# Exception error using C++ Thread Pool Library (CTPL)

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, visual-studio-2013, threadpool

I am trying to use the [C++ Thread Pool Library (CTPL)](https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL), which pleasantly consists in a single [header file](https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL/blob/master/ctpl_stl.h).

For this, I created a very simple test program. Here is the code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ctpl_stl.h"

void myFunction(int threadID_0)
{ 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}

int main()
{
    ctpl::thread_pool p(2); // We create the pool with 2 threads

    p.push(myFunction);     // We add work
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);
    p.push(myFunction);

    p.stop(true);           // We wait for all the tasks to be performed

    return 0;
}
```

When I excecute this program, sometimes it works, sometimes not (I get a message "R6010 - abort() has been called").

When I debug, the last function call for which the code is available is set_thread, and the error is at the line 202.

I noticed that it is easier to make it crash when I decrease or remove the timer.

Since this code is very simple, I must have missed something in the principle.
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `abort()` could be called due to an uncaught throw. If that's what's going on, figure out the type of the thrown object and if it's an exception, get the message.

Comment: I notice the sample doesn't call `stop` - just an observation

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce the error to make this statement doctorlove ? 
Anyway you are right, it crashes before calling stop.
And I can't manage to catch an exception.

Comment: I meant the sample code on github - not this code.

Comment: OK, but no actually stop is called by the destructor of the threadpool at the end of the main function. This sample is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file ctpl_stl.h is fixed on the project web site. Try the new version (0.0.2) instead of the old one. It should work, it works for me.

ctpl_stl.h was created as a modification of ctpl.h for convenience for the users who do not want to have dependancy on BOOST lockfree library.
ctpl.h is a better choice, it is well tested and should be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you have been very fast !